# Ordering by two columns not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a "Trending" list where the top 10 articles show up. The trend list is based on most recent and most views. This is what my current SQL query looks like:

```
$resultSet = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Articles ORDER BY Counter DESC, dateStamp LIMIT 10");
```

`Counter` is the column that stores how many views each article has. `dateStamp` is the datetime column that stores the datetime of each article. My current SQL works for the number of views. It orders the article that has the most views on top and the article that has least views on the bottom.

The only problem that I am experiencing with this current SQL is that it does not take the most recent dates only. It looks for all the dates and only orders the query based on views. An article could be 2 years long, but it'll have more views so it'll be in the trending list.

How can I make it so that the query orders the results based on both recent and most views?

**Example Data:**

> Date: 8/1/15  Views: 20,000
>
> Date: 9/30/16  Views: 500
>
> Date: 9/28/16  Views: 400
>
> Date: 9/25/16  Views: 150
>
> Date: 9/22/16  Views: 100
>
> Date: 9/21/16  Views: 98
>
> Date: 9/20/16  Views: 92
>
> Date: 9/18/16  Views: 10
>
> Date: 9/15/16  Views: 5
>
> Date: 9/12/16  Views: 3

**Technically, the data should look like this:**

> Date: 9/30/16  Views: 500
>
> Date: 9/28/16  Views: 400
>
> Date: 9/25/16  Views: 150
>
> Date: 9/22/16  Views: 100
>
> Date: 9/21/16  Views: 98
>
> Date: 9/20/16  Views: 92
>
> Date: 9/18/16  Views: 10
>
> Date: 9/15/16  Views: 5
>
> Date: 9/12/16  Views: 3
>
> Date: 9/11/16  Views: 2

It's not organizing the most recent dates. I need it to organize the most recent dates and the most views. The views part is working correctly, it's just the dates that's not.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  If you are asking us for a "reasonable" way to order the results, then your question should be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: Your options are : most views restricted by reasonable period, most recent restricted by reasonable number of views, a max of a weighting functions with reasonable weights of views and period.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated the question, please check

Comment: @Serg I want it to be most views restricted by the top 10 recent dates in the table. I have updated the question to satisfy how I want it to be

Comment: But the top 10 recent dates do not necessarily coincide with the top 10  most views.  The two are completely unrelated to each other.  You have not thought out very well what it is that you want.

Comment: Please give a CREATE TABLE statement and INSERT statements for at least 20 rows.

Comment: @MikeNakis I want the most recent dates ordered based on the number of views they have.

Comment: Then you need to compute date restriction first. Kind of  `(SELECT min(dateStamp) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT dateStamp FROM Articles ORDER BY dateStamp DESC,  LIMIT 10))` and use it in WHERE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to get the 10 most recent records:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles ORDER BY dateStamp DESC LIMIT 10;
```

This is how to order by views descending:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY Counter DESC;
```

The two combined:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM Articles ORDER BY dateStamp DESC LIMIT 10) TOP10
ORDER BY Counter DESC;
```

Comment: For some reason this doesn't print out any results

Comment: @user2896120 This should work. Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data?

Comment: This is what I have as a query statement: `$resultSet = $cn->query("SELECT * FROM (Articles ORDER BY dateStamp DESC LIMIT 10) ORDER BY Counter DESC");` No results show up so there's no sample data

Comment: This is different from what I wrote. You are missing the second `SELECT * FROM`.

Comment: @user2896120 I means sample **input** data, so we can try the query and see if it works. Your query has a syntax error, so it seems like you're not checking for errors when you execute queries or you would have seen it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Here's my sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60c7cc/2

Comment: @user2896120 You left out the `TOP10` alias after the subquery. That's why you get the error "Every derived table requires an alias". See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60c7cc/3

Comment: @barmar Oh okay, I didn't know I had to do that cause the poster's answer didn't have the AS keyword, so I thought TOP10 was just a reference. Thanks a lot! Works now

Comment: `AS` is optional before aliases. The alias itself is not optional.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a `where` to limit the dates that show up. The `order by` orders the results based on the first column. It only uses the second column if two rows have the same value for the first column.

Comment: `WHERE` could be used to limit it to a specific date range, but how would that be used to get the most recent 10 rows?